# Compare two columns of the same dataframe and returns a different column of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Unable to extract individual values from Column (Week) but a single value works.

```
u = eurusd.loc[eurusd['Local time'] == pd.to_datetime("2014-01-08 03:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")].Close
print(u)
```

output:

```
70275    1.36075
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

But when i try this:

```
u = eurusd.loc[eurusd['Local time'] == pd.to_datetime(eurusd['Week'],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")].Close
print(u)
```

output:

```
Series([], Name: Close, dtype: float64)
```

I also tried doing the same task with the apply method, but it seems to just compare the columns row by row, not an iterative one

```
eurusd['ResultClose'] = eurusd.apply(lambda eurusd: eurusd if eurusd['Local time'] == "2014-01-08 03:00:00" else np.nan,axis=1)
```

To double check code:

```
eurusd.isnull().sum()
```

output (Shows that no values were inserted in the column):

```
Local time        0
Close             0
ResultClose       8760
dtype: int64
```

The tables below give a visual of what am trying to achieve.

Initial table

| Local time | Close | Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 00:00:00 |
| 2014-01-01 01:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 01:00:00 |
| 2014-01-01 02:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 02:00:0 |
| 2014-01-08 03:00:00 | 1.36075 | 2014-03-08 02:00:0 |

Final table

| Local time | Close | Week | ResultClose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.36075 |
| 2014-01-01 01:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 01:00:00 | . |
| 2014-01-01 02:00:00 | 1.37410 | 2014-01-08 02:00:00 | . |
| 2014-01-08 03:00:00 | 1.36075 | 2014-03-08 02:00:0 | . |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly convert **'Local time'** and **'Week'** to datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()` method:

```
eurusd['Local time']=pd.to_datetime(eurusd['Local time'])
eurusd['Week']=pd.to_datetime(eurusd['Week'])
```

Now use boolean masking and `between()` method:

```
mask=eurusd['Local time'].between(eurusd.loc[0,'Week'],eurusd.loc[len(eurusd)-1,'Week'])
value=eurusd.loc[mask,'Close'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally use `assign()` method:

```
eurusd=eurusd.assign(ResultClose=value)
```

Now if you print `eurusd` you will get your desired output:

```
        Local time          Close           Week               ResultClose
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00     1.37410     2014-01-08 00:00:00     1.36075
1   2014-01-01 01:00:00     1.37410     2014-01-08 01:00:00     NaN
2   2014-01-01 02:00:00     1.37410     2014-01-08 02:00:00     NaN
3   2014-01-08 03:00:00     1.36075     2014-03-08 02:00:00     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to modify it a little because my data wasn't index from 0.
I used 
mask=eurusd['Week'].between(eurusd.loc[0,''Local time'],eurusd.loc[len(eurusd)-1,'Local time''])

Comment: If you wish, please consider accepting the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved (and also to keep people here motivated in helping others)..Thank you **:)**

Comment: So I noticed my solution was not given the right result so I flip it back.Since it was just an index issue I added this before the assign() method
value.index =pd.RangeIndex(start=eurusd1.first_valid_index(),stop=len(value)+eurusd1.first_valid_index(),step=1)